# Error code 100 Parse SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, parse-platform

I am intermittently getting an error while making Parse cloud calls in iOS,

Its either this error,

> The network connection was lost. (Code: 100, Version: 1.7.5)

or

> failed with error message: Request timed out (Code: 141, Version: 1.7.1)

I have Android client making same requests but it doesn't throw these errors.

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: Try restart simulator and XCode

Comment: Check your internet connectivity . Try some other website or link in simulator if that works. Seems your internet is very very slow or not connected.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? It's happening to me now on a simple test case, driving me quickly mad (using back4app backend).

Answer (score 0):

- Code 100 means: *The connection to the Parse servers failed.*

Maybe, you have no network connection, or `Parse.setApplicationId("", clientKey: "")` is not set, or I don't know, it can be for many reasons.

- Code 141: *Cloud Code script failed. Usually points to a JavaScript error in your script.*

Check your JS code, seems like is wrong.